# JFreeChart - listen for changes to series

Tags: java, jfreechart

How can I subscribe to a given JFreeChart object to be notified about changes to the series set i.e. a new series inserted or a new data point added to the series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Dataset:

```
Dataset coll = new XYSeriesCollection();
coll.addChangeListener(new DatasetChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void datasetChanged(DatasetChangeEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

or for the JFreeChart itself:

```
JFreeChart chart = createChart();
chart.addChangeListener(new ChartChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void chartChanged(ChartChangeEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

And I am sure, that also works for the Plots in between and the Series at the end.

EDIT: To only listen for added/removed series:

```
final XYSeriesCollection coll = new XYSeriesCollection();
coll.addChangeListener(new DatasetChangeListener() {
    private int numberOfSeries = -1;

    @Override
    public void datasetChanged(DatasetChangeEvent arg0) {
        int numberOfSeriesNew = coll.getSeriesCount();
        if (numberOfSeriesNew == numberOfSeries) {
            // no series was added/removed
        } else if (numberOfSeriesNew < numberOfSeries) {
            // series was removed
            numberOfSeries = numberOfSeriesNew;
        } else {
            // series was added
            numberOfSeries = numberOfSeriesNew;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I would only like to know if a new series was added or not. Is there a way to listen for that events?

Comment: Yes, use the `DatasetChangeListener` like I showed you above. As I think that changes within a series are also propagated to the DatasetChangeListener, you can then just monitor the number of series in the collection (if it has changed, a series was added/removed). You can use `arg0.getSeries()` to see which series was added/removed.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but it still not what I want. It is down to JFreeChart which does not allow it. I want to get a series key as well...

Comment: I don't know how to capture that directly. You could adapt my sample code to also save the set of series. If the numberCount has changed, you can go through the saved set and compare with the current set of series (use `Set#removeAll()` and `Set#addAll()` for that). This way you can find out, what series has been added/removed. Not very elegant though.